# Is there something like python __dict__ in Julia?

Tags: function, julia

Python has **dict**, **doc**, **init** and so on.
Is there something like that in Julia?
How can I know names of functions of Julia packages?

[image]

Comment: Could you provide information about what said functions do in Python? It will be easier for the Julia community to provide alternatives. As a partial answer, if you are working in the REPL or Jupyter, you can discover the functions in a package by doing YourPackage.<TAB> and that will give you the names. You can look the documentation of Dictionary and Constructor for things similar to dict and __init__() if that is what you are asking, but more clarification would help.

Comment: I have added a picture in my question. When you type "__doc__" in Python, you can see explains. Like that. Anyway thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In addition to the function `names` (e.g. `names(Gadfly)`), which is used for modules. If you want to get all the attributes of the object, there are two functions for that:

1. `fieldnames` - returns a list of the fields for the object
   e.g.

```
struct Point
  x
  y
end
```

```
> propertynames(Point(2,3))

(:x, :y)
```

`propertynames` - returns a list of all the properties for the object. Usually the same as fieldnames plus user-defined properties (in most cases, you should use this function instead of `fieldnames`)

Answer (score 5):

Use the `names` function to get a list of all names exported by a module (as this is what I assume you are looking for). Note that the list will in particular include: functions, types, variables, and other modules. Here is an excerpt from its docstring giving you more details:

> `names(x::Module; all::Bool = false, imported::Bool = false)`
>
> Get an array of the names exported by a `Module`, excluding deprecated names. If `all` is true, then the list also includes non-exported names defined in the module, deprecated names, and compiler-generated names. If `imported` is true, then names explicitly imported from other modules are also included.

Because of the Julia design you should be aware of two issues:

- some packages opt not to export names, but assume that they should be always qualified; this is the case of e.g. CSV.jl package
- objects other than functions can be made callable in Julia (types are callable as constructors, variables can be turned into [functors](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/methods/#Function-like-objects))